# Python: How do I export a list to a text file?

Tags: python, list, file, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm writing a program which

1. Opens a file
2. Checks whether a user is in the file
3. Updates the user's record
4. Finally, overwrites the original file with the updated data

I'm struggling with point 4 where I keep getting an error that my data is a list not a string.

My text file has 6 comma-delimited columns: user_name followed by 6 numbers, i.e.
joes bloggs,1,2,3,4,5,6

Here is my code:

```
fname = input('First name? ')
fname = fname.lower()
lname = input('Last name? ')
lname = lname.lower()
name = (fname + ' ' + lname)
score=8

with open('test.txt','r+') as df:
    data=[]
    for row in df:
        data.append(row.strip().split(','))
#for checking
    print(data)
    for row in data:
        if name == row[0]:
        #for checking
            print(row)
            row[3]=row[2]
            row[2]=row[1]
            row[1]=score
            second=row[2]
            third=row[3]
            scores = [float(score),float(second),float(third)]
            row[5]=float(int((float(score)+float(second)+float(third))/ 0.03)/100)
            row[4]=max(scores)
            #for checking
            print(row)

    df.seek(0)
    for row in data:
        for item in row:
            df.write(item + ',')
        df.write(row +'\n')
    df.truncate()
    df.close()
```

Comment: An what line number do you get the error?

Comment: you haven't defined `f`.

Comment: never mind.  i see `f` was a typo.  you meant `df`.

Comment: if you have lists of data use the csv  module

Comment: Its a good idea to include the stack trace that shows the error. It likely points right at `df.write(row +'\n')` because `row` is a `list` and you can only print strings. Since you've already written the row data, change that to `df.write('\n')` or follow the other excellent advice given here.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  
The error was in the line 
     [df.write(row + '\n')] 
becuase it was expecting strings only not integers.
I have fixed it with two key changes:
1. Switching integers to strings
            row[6]=str(float(int((float(score)+float(second)
                              +float(third))/ 0.03)/100))
            row[5]=str(max(scores))
2. Using the join(row) command:
"with open('test.txt','w') as df:
    for row in data:
        df.write(",".join(row) +'\n')"

Answer (score 0):

wow,  someone has been teaching you to write cobol in python.  but, to your question, you have looped through writing each item followed by a comma, then wrote the entire row.  That is where the error came in.  Try using the join function in your output:

```
for row in data:
    df.write(",".join(row) +'\n')
```

Comment: That's great for tidying up the rows (and not leaving a trailing comma), but its not the actual error.